# подскажите где ошибка: С помощью массивов создайте новый объект, сделав его ключами элементы первого массива, а значениями - элементы второго

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста - почему не выводит первый елемент и его ключ??

Даны следующие массивы:
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let arr2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
С помощью этих массивов создайте новый объект, сделав его ключами элементы первого массива, а значениями - элементы второго.

```
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    arr2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    arr = {};
for ( let elem in arr1 ) {
  let key = arr1[elem] ;
  arr[key] = arr2[elem];
  console.log(arr)
}
```

Вывод :

```
{
  "2": 7,
  "3": 8,
  "4": 9,
  "5": 10
}
```

Comment: потому что надо знать разницу между циклами `for..in` и `for..of` ..... Это намёк

Comment: Конечно же…. 
In - работает в объектах. 
Of - в массивах. 
Так как работаем с объектом - использовать нужно for in. 
@АлексейШиманский все верно? Если нет - поправьте пожалуйста 

Comment: Нет, не правильно. for..in  прекраснейшим образом работает с массивами. И вам нужно посмотреть их различия в документации......о по сути for in будет работать как укороченный синтаксис `for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++)`  если сильно упростить

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  пошла читать различия… благодарю Вас

Comment: вы все правильно думаете. for in не для массивов. это стандартная ошибка новичков, так что не пугайтесь. нужно использовать for(;;), собственно вам ответ уже написали

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) сохраняет в переменную само значение, а не индекс.

Так как нужно пройтись по индексам, лучше воспользоваться обычным [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  arr2 = [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  arr = {};
for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
  let key = arr1[i];
  arr[key] = arr2[i];
}

console.log(arr)
```